# react-hook-form: How to remove the data values if the components are not rendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input defaultValue="test001" {...register("var001")} />
    {somecondition && (
        <>
            <input defaultValue="test002" {...register("var002")} />
            <input defaultValue="test003" {...register("var003")} />
        </>
    )}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have the following react hook form.

I want `console.log(data)` to print only of the rendered elements.

So if `somecondition` is not `true`

I want to see in `console.log(data)`

```
data = {
     "var001": "test001"
}
```

So if `somecondition` is `true`

I want to see in `console.log(data)`

```
data = {
     "var001": "test001"
     "var002": "test002",
     "var003": "test003",
}
```

How can i do this

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-55q98

showing the image

[image]

Comment: Maybe you missed something, but your code is working as it should with `somecondition` https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-9tghw

Comment: I was using `console.log(watch())`, that shows all. But you are right its working well

Comment: With `console.log(watch())` it's work the same, as needed

Comment: i have added a checkbox. In the beginning when loads first it works, but if we use checkbox to show and hide, then date show all inputs. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-55q98

Comment: Yup, a wrote answer belowe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all the fields you want to display if the condition is `true` in the `array`. Then it will be convenient to manipulate them and `unregister` needed fields if condition is `false` in `setShow` function. I wrote example for you.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-jr93u)

Comment: So i have to use unregister for this. thanks

Comment: can you check this question. related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101161/react-hook-form-how-to-remove-the-item-which-is-mentioned-in-defautvalue-from.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `shouldUnregister` to `true` to tell RHF to remove the field if the component is unmounted. This property was removed in v7 initially but get added again in the newer version so you need to update RHF to the latest version 7 to use it:

```
npm i react-hook-form@latest
```

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    var001: 'test001',
    var002: 'test002',
    var003: 'test003',
  },
  shouldUnregister: true,
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: but generally we use https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator (Inline If with Logical && Operator). Will that not work

Comment: @Santhosh see my updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-q2059. I have created a sandbox with your code. its not working

Comment: @Santhosh my bad, I misread your question and thought you want the opposite. It should be fixed now .

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my issue, the unregister() was throwing "too many re-renders" all the time.. Thanks!