# react-hook-form: how to remove the item (which is mentioned in defautvalue) from submit data if its not mounted. Tried unregister its not working

Tags: react-hook-form

I have simple form with `firstName` and `lastName`. I have added some `defaultValues` to them in `useForm`. I havent mounted the `lastName` using if condition.

Now when I try to submit, I am expecting it to show only the mounted components values i.e `firstName`. But it shows both `firstName` and `lastName`. I have created a button to try to `unregister("lastName")` but even after unregister and not being mounted it shows in the submit data.

If I dont provide `defaultValues` then it works well, like if not mounted initially it will not be shown in the submit data.

Below is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, unregister, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "test",
      lastName: "test2"
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("ON SUBMIT");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
  };


  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input {...register("firstName")} />
      {false && (
        <>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input {...register("lastName")} />
        </>
      )}
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("unregistering lastName")
          unregister("lastName");
        }}
      >
        unregister lastName
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-unregister-v6-forked-rriop?file=/src/index.js:0-1038)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, you can't use `unregister("lastName");` before `register("lastName");` it's useless. Second, when you use `defaultValues`, method `unregister` does not remove them but simply set values to default. You just can filter submit data by conditions without `unregister`. [Demo](http://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-jr93u)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107519/2897115 this is the right answer I think. I cant filter like that. Because there are many such checkboxes. It can become too messy

Comment: This property `shouldUnregister` was removed in v7 initially but get added again in the newer version so you need to update RHF to the latest version 7 to use it

Comment: any how another thing i faced is certain defaultValues i want to show. So your option only will fit my needs