# react-hook-form: Dont show default values in submit data when they are not mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I observe that if I mention `defaultValues` like below

```js
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "test",
      lastName: "test2"
    }
  });
```

and dont mount the `lastName`

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input {...register("firstName")} />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I see `onSubmit`

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
};
```

I see the following

```js
{
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test2"
}
```

But i wish to see only the `firstName` since i havent mounted the `lastName`

```js
{
    "firstName": "test",
}
```

[image: Edit react-hook-form-unregister-v6 (forked)]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `shouldUnregister` for this, from the [Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform):

> By default, an input value will be retained when input is removed.
> However, you can set `shouldUnregister` to true to unregister input
> during unmount.

```js
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "test2"
  },
  shouldUnregister: true
});
```

[image: Edit react-hook-form-unregister-v6 (forked)]

Comment: thanks struggling for this since a long time.